# type Prepend and Tail handles arrays, but extends to functions?

Tags: typescript, extends

I am fairly confused on how this type works. It accepts an array and extends to a function? Shouldn't it extend to an array? As it's an array that it's handling? I hope someone can explain why it extends to a function and what is U?

```
   type Prepend<E, T extends any[]> =
       ((head: E, ...args: T) => any) extends ((...args: infer U) => any)
       ? U
       : T
```

This second type also behaves similarly. It accepts an array, but handles it as a function.

```
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> = 
   ((...t:T) => any) extends ((_:any, ...tail: infer TT) => any) 
   ? TT 
   : []
```

Examples:

```
type T1 = Tail<[1,2,3]>  //2 ,3
type T2 = Tail<["A","B","C"]> // "B" , "C"
type T3 = Tail<[1,"A","Hello"]> //"A", "Hello"

type P1 = Prepend<string, []> //[string]
type P2 = Prepend<number, [1,2]> //[number,1,2]
```

Comment: These are very archaic implementations that were used before variadic tuple types were introduced. Here are modern implementations: https://tsplay.dev/mA84kN

Comment: Rest parameters can have tuple types, as described [in the TS3.0 release notes](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  A function type `(a: string, b: number) => void` is the same as `(a: string, ...args: [number]) => void` is the same as `(...args: [string, number]) => void`.  So you can infer tuple types for pieces of argument lists and use it to join/split tuples (but this is not necessary since TS4.0). Does that fully address the question? If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not what am I missing?

Comment: If possible, I'd like more elaboration regarding  the function that it extends to on both examples. What is infer U and what is infer TT? What is extending to? It's difficult to even explain my question as it's something that I'm very unfamiliarized with despite being an antique approach.

Comment: I hope you don't need an entire explanation of [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types), do you?  I mean, do you understand the basics of how `infer` works?

Comment: I understand the basics of infer. Don't worry.

Comment: Okay I'll write that up in an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Before [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) were introduced, there was no direct way to join or split [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  Today you'd write

```
type Prepend<E, T extends any[]> = [E, ...T];
type X = Prepend<1, [2, 3, 4]>;
// type X = [1, 2, 3, 4];

type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends readonly [any, ...infer TT] ? TT : [];
type Y = Tail<["a", "b", "c"]>
// type Y = ["b", "c"];
```

The `Prepend` type is now fairly useless since it's longer than just using variadic tuples directly.  But with `Tail` you can still see what's going on if you understand [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  The compiler is matching the `T` type to some tuple whose first element is `any` (which will match anything pretty much) and where the *rest* of the tuple is some `infer`red type `TT`, and it evaluates to `TT`.

---

But before that, the only route available to do this was to translate between tuple types and function parameters.  There's a natural mapping between tuples like `[string, number]` and functions like `(a: string, b: number) => any`, and the compiler supports all sorts of translations between them, as described [in the TypeScript 3.0 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).

Note that the names of function parameters (and the *labels* of [labeled tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) which also came out later) do not affect the typings, so in what follows `(a: string) => any` and `(x: string) => any` are the same.  And `(...args: [string]) => any` and `(...rest: [string]) => any` and `(...blfdsjksdksjk: [string]) => any` are the same.

Anyway, a function of type `(a: string, b: number) => any` has a parameter list of type `[string, number]`.  And since [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) let you package parameter lists into single argument positions, you can say that `(a: string, b: number) => any` and `(...args: [string, number]) => any` are the same type.  Now the relationship between function parameter lists and arguments should be more obvious.

Indeed all of these are the same type:

```
type F1 = (a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4) => any;
type F2 = (...args: [1, 2, 3, 4]) => any;
type F3 = (z: 1, ...args: [2, 3, 4]) => any;
```

Looking at `F3`, hopefully it makes sense that this happens:

```
type X = ((a: 1, ...args: [2, 3, 4]) => any) extends
  ((fgh: any, ...blrgh: infer TT) => any) ? TT : [];
// type X = [2, 3, 4]
```

it's pretty easy to match the first argument (since `any` matches anything) and then the rest parameter is of type `[2, 3, 4]`.  But since `F3` is the same as `F2`, you get

```
type X = ((...args: [1, 2, 3, 4]) => any) extends
  ((a: any, ...args: infer TT) => any) ? TT : [];
// type X = [2, 3, 4]
```

And just like that we've gotten the tail of the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` tuple, by translating from a tuple type to a function type, manipulating the function type, and then translating back to a tuple.  This technique could be made a utility type:

```
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> = 
   ((...t:T) => any) extends ((_:any, ...tail: infer TT) => any) 
   ? TT : []
```

which is what you were asking about.

Similarly with `Prepend`, you can match in the other direction, where you take a function of type `(head: E, ...args: T) => any` and try to infer it against `(...args: infer U) => any`, which will cause `U` to be the same as what we'd now call `[E, ...T]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAOSgdxQb2MFFAFwE85UAFAJynJABMAeAUQBoUAVFKADyKgYwUYECQDaAXQB8KALwoxbFADpVHCQG4CxMqgAaclNVoCmARnZiATOwDM7ACzSthAPSud5FAfliLKGxR7FCctbVIvDjAASwAbRi5efkEUGjB6AHsQWJJhUUkZeUS+UyE0zOzcsRESdlVlaJAAMygqTnUUAH52lAAuBU1w3RQATUMouMYxACIwafZpgCN5lGnEaeltd09UMd8llbWNsOAAX1BIWARkFAB5WPpcfEIIyho6JiVi5PohGoK5NpCAAKYEACyg6X6SnqYCoAHMYP0OABKOQyGpopKlFCg2EIpEoRotNoAVTRsgxohRQK6KFJtORzx2KAAYmZDMCwP1-It+oFEP1gvR+g4KVSSC4WayrJz8Yj+n52IFgk5xXlJUMvKzbJzuSh-PLCdY7I4JOqamEXsMfLiuTy6qo4QqFCqzRbqdwSoJaaD9TVHcpnYTia12h6SGjuhwuIrBm4PK9vIYxHyAuxBUF2CKQhJmUmJvFvjjylkchqAbJfcD6kRkRGsd7fnaAPr9AMqVREGKxfqhtoxhu06McRkDfCnIA)